# AngularJS: pass data to directive with existing controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I will try to make a sketch of the issue I'm trying to tackle:

On a page on my website I load in a dataset. This data needs to be organized into a grid. When routing to a page, the data is resolved and it is accessible in the global page controller.

For the grid I am trying to make a directive which is responsible for the proper placing of the data-items (according to some rules the data is passed through).

I was thinking of using something like this in the main page:

```
<data-grid demoData="dataset"></data-grid>
```

I would then assign an existing controller which has all logic to order the data in the correct way to the dataGrid directive.
At its turn the template of the data-grid would be something like this:

```
<div class="grid"><data-item ng-repeat="item in data-items"></data-item></div>
```

At the moment I am stuck with this setup, I can't seem to pass the data to the dataGrid directive. 
Could anyone show me an ideal setup / example of how to process this kind of data?

At the moment my grid directive looks like this:

```
cardGrid.directive('cardGrid', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'views/partials/cardGrid.html',
        replace:true,
        controller: 'gridCtrl',
        scope: {
           demoData: '='
        }
    };
});
```

but I cannot seem to be able to access the dat in the gridCtrl.
Or should I be using the link function or compile function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the data set in the 'demoData' attr, you definitely need to use the link function :

```
cardGrid.directive('cardGrid', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'views/partials/cardGrid.html',
    replace:true,
    scope: {
      demoData: '='
    },
    link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
       console.info(scope.demoData);
    }
};
});
```

The controller option is a special type of controller : a directive controller.This controller is only defined within the context of this directive (and can be injected inside others directives) but it probably isn't what you are looking for.

EDIT : to reply to your comment, if you wish to shorten the size of your link function you can indeed use the controller option. 
See this example : https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/accordion/accordion.js

Comment: Ok, I will now try to move all logic from the controller to the link function. Only bummer is that the link function will become very large and this will decrease the readability of the directive. Will keep you up to date.